# Can't save the same record twice in the join table Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have 2 tables, `Invoice` and `Product`, and I'm using EF to save data to my database

The two classes and my context class are as following:

```
public class Invoice
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DB() : base("MyConnectionstringName") { }

    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, this is how I save data to the database:

```
public string Create(Invoice invoice, List<Product> products)
{
        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            invoice.Products.Add
                (db.Products.Find(item.id));
        }
        db.Invoices.Add(invoice);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ...
        return "Invoice was successfully saved";
}
```

The problem is, if I have the same Product twice in the `products`, I gets added to the join table in the database, only once.
For example, if a customer buys two `Pepperoni pizza` which has the Id of 5, after saving, there will be only of row of data in `InvoiceProduct` pointing to this particular invoice, and ProductId of 5.

Everything is fine up until `db.Invoices.Add(invoice);`, cause when I check `invoice` in debug mode I can see several of the same item were added to its `Products` property, but when it gets saved to the database, it only get saved once.

And it works just fine with several of different products for the same invoice.

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: I guess `Id` is set as [PRIMARY KEY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.ASP) for `Product` table on database. It isn't?

Comment: auto generated join table has composite primary key of InvoiceId and ProductId .so combination of invoiceId and productId must be unique. that is why only one row was added by ef for same invoiceid and productid

Comment: @a_k So there is no way for a customer to order two of the same product in one invoice? By the way I checked the join table, there is no index who involves both ProductId and InvoiceId, there are two separate not unique indexes for each of them, and one unique for Id field of the join table itself

Answer (score 0):

In sql relational world you have the Products table, the Invoice table and the ProductsInvoices table that represents a many-to-many relationship. In that table you have the reference for an id of a product and an id of an invoice. When you add it twice EF understand that you already have the relation you want and does nothing.

In order to solve this I would create other class named InvoiceItem having a Product, an Invoice and a Quantity:

```
public class Invoice
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public List<InvoiceItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceItem
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public List<InvoiceItem> Invoices { get; set; }
}

public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DB() : base("MyConnectionstringName") { }

    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

It is recommended that you also add the copy of the item description and price of the Product in the InvoiceItem object, because if in the future the user changes the price or name of the product it doesn't alter the Invoice that were generated in the past.

Comment: Yes it came to my mind too, but isn't this just a "ProductsInvoices" with an extra field as Quantity? Cause even though you haven't declared a reference to "Invoice" in the "InvoiceItems", but since Invoice has a property of a list of InvoiceItems, EF will create a foreign key as InvoiceId in InvoiceItems table. so the table would have Id, InvoiceId, ProductId, and Quantity, right?

Comment: Thing is that in EF World you don't have the ProductsInvoices class if you don't declare it explicitly. EF creates the tables automatically if you create the navigation properties, but you cannot add the Quantity property unless you create the ProductsInvoices object.